# Jersey 1.19 vs Validation

Tags: java, jersey

II know that Jersey 1.19 is using the JAX-RS 1.1 rather than 2.x and therefore feature no bean validation.

Is there a clever way or a special pattern one can use to ease the pain? What is (beside upgrading) one preferable approach?

Comment: I think this is exhaustive, I used to follow it until I got the chance to upgrade (finally): http://maxenglander.com/2013/01/11/validating-jersey-request.html